# The key hash does not match any stored key hashes in facebook react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I ma working on react-native latest version 60+. I am integrate the facebook login on debug mode but get the issue error:

```
Error: SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: The key hash does not match any stored key hashes. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android for more information. [extra]:
```

I am open the new terminal and got the key hash using is command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And add the bebug key hash on facebook developers. But I am get the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use file in `android/app/debug.keystore`

```
cd <your project>
```

then

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore android/app/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: I am get the Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore android/app/debug.keystore -destkeystore android/app/debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12"

Comment: where were you by now , You saved my day. I was doing it all wrong , we need local (project > android) folder debug.keystore to get the correct key. because the project was created on another computer , I had different key of the project than my main android/debug.keystore key . most of documents suggest to get global one, thats why we get it all wrong.